# Foreach loop only validates first element

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement, foreach, xamarin.ios

I'm validating `TextFields` with a `foreach` loop with an `if/else` statement inside. This all happens inside a `public virtual Boolean Method()`. Only the first element is validated and I don't know why the rest is not validated.

How do I have to change my method so it will validate all the items in `TextFieldList`?

This is my method:

```
public virtual Boolean ValidateTextFields(){

    foreach (UITextField item in TextFieldList) {
        if (item.Text == "") {
            item.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString (item.Placeholder, foregroundColor: UIColor.Red);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I got it working but now I have another issue, I have multiple methods like `ValidateTextFields` and I check them like this:

```
if (ValidateTextFields() && ValidateEmail() ) {
    Console.WriteLine ("CONTINUE TO NEXT SCREEN");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine ("ERRORRRRRR");
}
```

Now if `ValidateTextFields()` is `false` then `ValidateEmail()` is never called so the `EmailTextFields` won't be validated. Only after `ValidateTextFields()` is `true` I can validate `ValidateEmail()`. Is there a way to call both methods at the same time and check if they are `true`?

Comment: Do you really need to return `true/false` inside your foreach loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: 
If have any invalid field the Method returns false, else if all fields is valid returns true.

```
  public virtual Boolean ValidateTextFields(){

        foreach (UITextField item in TextFieldList) {
            if (item.Text == "") {
                item.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString (item.Placeholder, foregroundColor: UIColor.Red);
                return false;
            } 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Or you can valid all itens to put a attributedplaceholder for each item and returns if has any invalid, like this:

```
  public virtual Boolean ValidateTextFields(){
        bool hasInvalidFields = false;
        foreach (UITextField item in TextFieldList) {
            if (item.Text == "") {
                item.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString (item.Placeholder, foregroundColor: UIColor.Red);
                hasInvalidFields = true;
            } 
        }
        return !hasInvalidFields;
    }
```

For your edit, to call all validates you can:

```
bool validTextFields = ValidateTextFields();
bool validEmails = ValidateEmail();

if ( validTextFields &&  validEmails) {
    Console.WriteLine ("CONTINUE TO NEXT SCREEN");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine ("ERRORRRRRR");
}
```

Comment: Only issue from this is you might need to set _all_ invalid `item.AttributePlaceholder` values; this would only set the first invalid one and ignore any potentially other invalid items.

Comment: Your second code works fine but now I have another issue, I've edited my question.

Comment: @speetje33 why would you want to call the second methods even when the first is already false?

Comment: Because if a user forgets one `Normal` TextField he will get an error. If he fills the TextField and will press on the `Save` button he will get another error for the `Email` TextField. I would like to show boths errors at the same time. If I would be the user I would be annoyed with 2 different errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will *always* return after the first element has been processed, whether it's valid or not.

What you probably want instead is to validate all elements and return *afterwards*:

```
var result = true;
foreach (UITextField item in TextFieldList) {
    if (item.Text == "") {
        item.AttributedPlaceholder = 
         new NSAttributedString (item.Placeholder, foregroundColor: UIColor.Red);
        result = false;
    } 
}

return result;
```

You simply need to remember what to return in the end instead of returning immediately.

Comment: Your code works fine but I have another issue now because I got multiple methods, I've edited my question.

Comment: @speetje33: `var one = ValidateOne(), two = ValidateTwo(); if (one && two) ... `.